# play framework 2.6 ws cannot resolve

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, playframework, sbt

I use play framework 2.6 
I need to send a http request to an url, so I use WS for sending this request
first I add below line to sbt.build

```
    libraryDependencies += ws
```

but in controller play cannot resolve ws package

```
    import play.libs.ws.*;
```

how can I add play.libs.ws to controller???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.6.3"
```

to build.sbt (where you can specify proper version instead of 2.6.3) and refresh SBT project.

Then

```
import play.libs.ws._
```

in Scala or

```
import play.libs.ws.*;
```

in Java should work.

If there is an issue with resolving dependencies try `sbt clean` + `sbt update` or re-import the project to IDE.

Comment: yeah it's work. I reimport project to IDE and it's be ok. very very thanks