# Exception in Play Framework 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I Was using play framework 2.5.
My scala version is 2.11.8.
When I migrated to Paly 2.6, I'm getting the following error

```
RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/libs/ws/WSRequest$class
```

Comment: Please check these answers: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139392/5249621 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175035/5249621

Answer (score 1):

WS was extracted to it's own library, so you need to add in the `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += ws
```

You can find more details in the official documentation:    https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS

And do not forget the migration guide:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/WSMigration26

Comment: That's would rather happen when mixing WS versions, directly or not (dependency hell)